# Duplicated rows merge in one row adding new columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data

```
| id | name | action|

| 1  | user1| action1|

| 2  | user2| action1|

| 3  | user1| action56|

| 4  | user3| action49|

| 5  | user1| action649|
```

and I want to get this:

```
| id | name | action | action2 | action3 |

| 1  | user1| action1| action56| action649|

| 2  | user2| action1|

| 4  | user3| action49|
```

I already know how to get the firsts duplicates and last ones, but I don't know how to "transform" the dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `pivot` problem after using `groupby` + `cumcount` create the key

```
df.assign(key=df.groupby('name').cumcount()+1).pivot('name','key','action').add_prefix('action_')
key    action_1  action_2   action_3
name                                
user1   action1  action56  action649
user2   action1      None       None
user3  action49      None       None
```

Comment: Thanks ! it fits my problem, I just added 
`pd.DataFrame(pivot_table.to_records())`
 to get a dataframe object which is more suitable for my problem.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 keeping review the good q&a answers in so, also not short cut just do more practice :-)

Answer (score 0):

you need [groupby.transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html),

```
df['action']=df.groupby('name')['action'].transform(','.join)

df=df.drop_duplicates('name')
print(df)
#id name    action
#0  1   user1   action1, action56, action649
#1  2   user2   action1
#3  4   user3   action49
```